# Layout of report not properly after exported to PDF

Tags: visual-studio-2008, rdlc

I added RDLC reports to website, this site support multiple language (English & Arabic).
My problem is, when I change the layout of the site to Arabic and export RDLC report to PDF using the ReportViewer the reports layout appear left to right, I need to show them right to left.
I tried to make the Direction property for all elements of the report to be RTL , but with no luck.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I know that in version 2005 of VS the solution for this was to place all the report objects
in a List object and set the list Direction property to RTL.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I fixed it by setting the Direction property of your textBox to RTL; It's tiredfull but you have to do that for all the TextBoxes in your report!